# White space nowrap but break line if greater than max width in css

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I use `white-space: nowrap` so my string will stay in one line but I also set `max-width: 100px` because I want the string to break only when over the `max-width`, makes sense only the two parameters conflicts each other. The `white-space` property "overpower" the `max-width` property and the string stay in one line.

```
<div class="mydiv">this is my text</div>
```

```
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I tried "playing" with `overflow-wrap` property but that didn't work either.

If I remove the `white-space` property, the string break word by word, each word in a new line. That's happening because the element is `position: absolute`, I think..

So how do I solve this?

Comment: It seems like just by removing `white-space: nowrap` would solve your problem - No wrap below 100px and wrap above 100px.

Comment: read again please @HaoWu

Comment: I... still don't get it. Why not just remove it so it will automatically wrap if it reaches `100px` width?

Comment: Not possible with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D so what? javascript?

Comment: Yes. You might try a wrapper with the max-width instead though and the lose the no-wrap.

Comment: my answer is not helpful?

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove the white-space property, the string break word by word, each word in a new line. That's happening because the element is position: absolute, I think

It happens because of the `left:50%` that will restrict the width of your element to a maximum width equal to 50% of the containing block width.

Add a negative `margin-right` to avoid this issue

```css
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-right:-50%;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">this is my text this is my text this is my text this is my text this is my text</div>
```

Without the margin trick the item will wrap sooner:

```css
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">this is my text this is my text this is my text this is my text this is my text</div>
```